# Powerpoint missing resolve action for comments

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, office365

When using powerpoint, sometimes the comments have the "resolve" action but sometimes they don't.

I could not figure out where it could have been configured or if it is related with powerpoint versions.

When resolve action is available it shows like this:
[image: Resolve enabled]

On the other hand when it is not available it shows like this:
[image: Resolve NOT enabled]

The behavior (resolve button being available or not) is consistent between application and browser. So I don't think it is related with PowerPoint versions.

I suspect, it may have something to do with the first commenter being from the organization or not. But I don't have any supporting material for this "idea".

Anyone who knows what dictates the resolve button behaviour?

Comment: Another line of thought:  were some of the comments created in an earlier version of PPT, one that doesn't support so-called Modern comments? I'm not sure what the effect of that might be, but it's worth asking.

Comment: I checked that also. But same version seems behaving differently.